# JSON-RPC Connection Pool Implementation

Tags: json-rpc

I am using go-Ethereum ethclient and rpc packages to interact with block chain nodes to communicate via JSON-RPC.
I usually code below two lines to get connection to the node and then use any of the method depends on operation

1. client, err := rpc.Dial(jsonrpcURL)
2. ethClient := ethclient.NewClient(client)
3. do operation for example pendingNonceat or SendTransaction

Now this works fine. But curious how this connection is handled when heavy traffic is coming in to my package.  Does the same ehtClient can be used for all incoming requests or do we need to maintain our own connection pool to handle ?
I am not sure does the library providing out of the box pooling here ?